# Activity restarts when rotating Android phone

Tags: android, android-activity

My activity restarts when I rotate my phone.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This is not actually a "bug." I would highly recommend taking a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

add

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

to your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Save your non-view instance state in onSaveInstanceState or in onRetainNonConfigurationState and restore state in onCreate. Save "shared document-like data" in onPause() by writing to a database and restoring "shared document-like data" in onResume().

Also see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are various posts on this, but for [Android Version 3.2 and newer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android/9550231#9550231) you should add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, as the screen size changes between landscape and portrait orientation.

Comment: Obviously this is the lazy way of solving things!